# How to query map properties in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm learning HQL and I've an object with a Map property like this:

```
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "InfoLicenzaOrdine", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "infolicenza"))
    @Column(length = 64000)
    public Map<String, String> getInformazioniDiLicenza() {
        return informazioniDiLicenza;
    }

    public void setInformazioniDiLicenza(
            Map<String, String> informazioniDiLicenza) {
        this.informazioniDiLicenza = informazioniDiLicenza;
    }
```

Now an HQL query like:

```
 select ordine from Ordine ordine where ordine.informazioniDiLicenza['codiceAccisa1'] = 'IT00NOV00029W'
```

will return all the objects with that value for that particular key of the map. What if I just want all the objects with that value regardless of the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ordine from Ordine ordine 
    where 'IT00NOV00029W' in elements(ordine.informazioniDiLicenza)
```

**See also:**

- [16.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

Comment: says org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token... That is the first "("

Answer (score 2):

In case when 'IT00NOV00029W' is stored by any key Ordine will be selected. Be carefull